# Torrent client on Windows 10 IoT

Tags: windows-iot

Are there any torrent client applications which work on a Raspberry Pi 2 running  Windows 10 IoT?

Comment: did you install windows 10 IoT?  it's extremely limited.

Comment: It not limited.. it just hasn't got binaries made up for it, yet. Like saying a brand new house isnt fit for purpose cause it dont got carpets or a fridge... luckily they made all things eventually.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, no.
But there is an app that allows you to remotely drive a torrent box.
more info here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/remotorr/9nblggh42q62
Hope it'll help...

Answer (score -2):

no, there aren't :( but i have found https://github.com/mono/monotorrent
but for raspbian wheezy there are avaliable clients with webui, eg deluge, qbittorrent, rtorrent+frontends, transmission!